# Can’t run the Minio client

Tags: minio

I am a complete beginner and I was just introduced to minIO and I wanted to run it for a local project. Now I wanted to run minIO on Docker and also its client on Docker.

So I take a quick look at the documentation and I setup the Minio image in my docker. I also was able to successfully fo to my port 9000 and access it using the access key and the secret key. The interface works fine.
Now I want to download the MinIO client and access the interface from the command line such as I want to run “mc ls” and get some response back. So I stop my Minio container and I write the commands mentioned in the documentation, “docker pull minio/mc” and “docker run minio/mc ls play” and now when I try to start the container of minio/mc in Docker it exits immediately.

I cannot get the client to start and neither can I run any mc commands from my macOS terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Every instance of the docker container for minio/mc can only run 1 command while creating the container such as docker run minio/mc command (eg: docker run minio/mc ls). Then the container is useless, so for a mac PC the better option is to install the mc client using Homebrew.

$ brew install minio